# Page/print sheet music layout program in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

The goal of my project idea is to convert an ASCII Markdown-like text into chord chart sheet music similar to the attached image (but with some graphical elements around the text that make it more of a hybrid of plain old chord charts and traditional musical notation.) I was looking at MAUI because I would like to run on laptop or tablet.

The question is: Will I be able to create layouts sized to **real-world measurements** like Letter size paper, with the **option to print** them? I would need to be able to measure text in a particular font to know where to **place graphical elements around the text**, and to know where to "word wrap" the next (musical) measure's bounds further down the page. I would also like it to be interactive such that you can click/tap to enable/disable (probably by graying them out) verses, etc. on the fly.

I am coming from many years in desktop Winforms. I would have gone straight to Winforms but tablet ports would (probably?) be a pain. I have a tiny bit of exposure to WPF.

[image: chord chart sheet music]

Comment: Generating a PDF would probably be the best approach

Comment: I have messed briefly with PdfSharp in the past. This forfeits the desired interactivity requirement, though, and some kind of on-screen layout would still be needed to preview the page.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/) to check if it helps.